# C# Null reference when parsing a float

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code below. Which works great expect I want to allow MaxDemand to be a null value. But since i'm parsing a string it seems to error if I don't put in some value.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Whats the best solution to implement an error handling solution? I tried float.TryParse but can't get that to work.

Thank you for looking over my issue.

```
    protected void GridView3_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
    float Cost = 0.0F; 
    float Consumption = 0.0F;
    int InvoiceID = 0;
    float MaxDemand = 0.0F;
    DateTime ServiceFrom = new DateTime();
    DateTime ServiceTo = new DateTime();

    foreach (string key in e.NewValues.Keys)
        switch (key)
        {
            case "TotalInvoice": Cost = float.Parse(e.NewValues[key].ToString()); 
                                break;
            case "EnergyInvoiceID": InvoiceID = int.Parse(e.NewValues[key].ToString()); 
                                break;
            case "Consumption": Consumption = float.Parse(e.NewValues[key].ToString()); 
                                break;
            case "ServiceFrom": ServiceFrom = DateTime.Parse(e.NewValues[key].ToString());
                                break;
            case "ServiceTo":   ServiceTo = DateTime.Parse(e.NewValues[key].ToString());
                                break;
            case "MaxDemand": MaxDemand = float.Parse(e.NewValues[key].ToString());
                                break;
        }

    UpdateInvoice(InvoiceID, Cost, Consumption, ServiceFrom, ServiceTo, MaxDemand);
    GridView3.EditIndex = -1;
    PopulateAccountHistory();
}
```

Comment: Your problem is probably that one of those e.NewValues[key] is returning null and the .ToString() call fails when called on a null value, but I'm guessing; if you can post the stacktrace of the exception it will probably be clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here isn't in the actual parsing of the `float` or `double` value.  If that failed it would return a more specific exception.  It appears that the problem is one of the returns of `e.NewValues[key]` is returning `null` and you are throwing on the call to `ToString`

It would be best to centralize the `null` checks at the start of the loop.  It would also allow you to remove the repeated calls to `e.NewValues[key]`.

```
 foreach (string key in e.NewValues.Keys) {
   var value = e.NewValues[key];
   if (value == null) { 
       continue;
   }

   var str = value.ToString();
   switch (key) {
     case "TotalInvoice": 
       Cost = float.Parse(str);
       break;

     ...
```

Comment: Thanks JaredPar for explaining my issue and showing me how to fix it. This really helped and fixed my problem! I owe you a beer!

Answer (score 1):

How about using a nullable type and checking the e.NewValues[Key] is not null

```
float? MaxDemand;
```

and then

```
case "MaxDemand": 
{
   if(e.NewValues[key] != null)
   {
     MaxDemand = float.Parse(e.NewValues[key].ToString());
   }
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my `NullableExtensions`:

```
public static T? Parse<T>(object obj)
    where T : struct
{
    if (obj == null) return null;
    try
    {
        return (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T));
    }
    catch (FormatException) { return null; }
    catch (InvalidCastException) { return null; }
}

case "TotalInvoice": Cost = NullableExtensions.Parse<float>(e.NewValues[key]); break;
```

Comment: Don't you need a `where T : struct` in that method signature?